# SQL SELECT products WHERE 'average price per product' < value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I'd like to only return prod_id's that have an average price < 7. Looking at the sample below, the query should only return prod_id 1 (average price = 5)

```
+---------+-------+
| prod_id | price | 
+---------+-------+
| 1       | 3     |
| 1       | 4     |
| 1       | 8     |
| 2       | 12    |
| 2       | 14    |
+---------+-------|
```

So the desired results should be:

```
+---------+-------+
| prod_id | avg_pr| 
+---------+-------+
| 1       | 5     |
+---------+-------|
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT prod_id, AVG(price) 
FROM products
WHERE AVG(price) < 7
GROUP BY prod_id
```

It's giving me this error: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't use an aggregation function in the where clause, you need to use [HAVING](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) for that:

```
SELECT prod_id, AVG(price) 
  FROM products
  GROUP BY prod_id
  HAVING AVG(price) <7;
```

Answer (score 5):

if you use your query, you will get an error said 'Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function
', please try this query

```
select id, avg(price) AS average from a group by id having avg(price)<7;
```